# Publishing site gives permission error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Code First migrations and up to this point that process has been working correctly. I have created a new user and I have added the following permissions to them:

```
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.__MigrationHistory TO MY_USER
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.__MigrationHistory TO MY_USER
GRANT DELETE ON dbo.__MigrationHistory TO MY_USER
GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.__MigrationHistory TO MY_USER
```

But when the site is published, my new Migration is not inserted into the table and I get an error

```
Cannot find the objects "Person" because it does not exist or you do not have permission
```

Is this down to a missing permission and if so which one am I missing? As you can see I have the basic CRUD added for that table.

Comment: There are several things that can cause this issue. Have you tried to connect to your production SQL Server with some type of tool like SSMS?

Comment: Yes I am able to login to SSMS with my new user and I can see all the tables including the one above and its contents. But when I publish, its not adding a new migration to the table - and yes I have the checkbox ticked in the publish wizard

Comment: Are you using a different user account than the one you used to create your database?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears i need to run the following permissions on the new user

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'my_user'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'my_user'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', 'my_user'
```

And the site will now publish/retrieve the migrations.